# Private Setter saying setter method is "not used"

Tags: java, private, setter

I'm writing a program that takes user input for employees. I have some private setters (they have to be private according to the UML) but the method names are underlined grey. I've tried making getters or doing this.variableName to get rid of them, but to be honest I don't have much experience with private setters so I'm unsure of what to do. Also there is no getters for some variables and no default constructor as shown in the UML.

UML:

[image: UML]

and here's my code

```
public class Employee_Kubik {
    
    //variables
    private static String name;
    private double salary;
    private int yearsWith;
    private double sales;
    
    public Employee_Kubik(String n, double sala, int y, double sale){
        name = n;
        salary = sala;
        yearsWith = y;
        sales = sale;
    } //Employee end
    
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    } //getName end
    
    private void setSalary(double s){
        if (s > 0){
            salary = s;
        } //if end
        else{
            salary = 0;
        } //else end
    } //setSalary end
    
    private void setYearsWith(int yw){
        if (yw > 0){
            yearsWith = yw;
        } //if end
        else{
           yearsWith = 0;  
        } //else end
    } //setYearsWith
    
    private void setSales(double s){
        if(s > 0){
            sales = s;
        } //if end
        else{
            sales = 0;
        } //else end
    } //setSales end
    
    public boolean promote(){
        if(sales > 9999 && yearsWith > 2){
            return true;
        } //if end
        else{
            return false;
        } //else end
    } //promote end
    
    public double calculateRaise(){
        salary = salary * 0.05;
        
        return salary;
    } //calculateRaise end
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Employee Name: " +
                name +
                ", has been with the company for " +
                yearsWith +
                " years and last year sold a total of $" +
                sales +
                "\nPromotion Status = " +
                promote();
    } //toString end
    
} //class end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place that you can use them in, is your constructor:

```
public Employee_Kubik(String n, double sala, int y, double sale){
    name = n;
    setSalary(sala);
    setSales(sale);
    setYearsWith(y);
}
```